# How can i aa multi "-" with str_replace in PHP

Tags: php, input-mask

my str is :

```
999999999
```

Now, how can i add "-" in this str ?

my example with "-" :

```
99-9-9-99999
```

Comment: what is you rule ? where do you want to put a `-` ?

Comment: How is this a `jquery` question?

Comment: replace with what? Ar do you want do remove dashes?

Comment: Are you attempting to do this in an `input` as the user types?

Comment: i mean add"-" in str.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code -

```
    <?php
       $str = "999999999"; 
       $output =  substr($str,1,2)."-".substr($str,2,1)."-".substr($str,3,1)."-".substr($str,4,5);
       echo "$output";
    ?>
```

output - `99-9-9-99999`

Comment: Please don't answer poor quality questions, all you will do is encourage further poor quality questions

Comment: Thank you for answer. work it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_replace()` to format the number.

```
<?php
    $num = "999999999";
    $new_num = preg_replace("/([0-9]{2})([0-9]{1})([0-9]{1})([0-9]{5})/", "$1-$2-$3-$4", $num);
    echo $new_num;
?>
```

Output:

99-9-9-99999